# Verify a Firebase ID-token vs. fetching user data

Tags: php, firebase, jwt, firebase-admin

I'm building a simple PHP website that lets the user sign in with Google or Facebook. This is done on the client side, and the resulting ID-token and refreshtoken are then sent to my PHP script to identify the user in the database. After that I'm using "traditional" session based user handling. Thus, the Firebase tokens are fetched using the javascript SDK and are only used at the moment of login.

I'm currently using the [unofficial Firebase Admin PHP SDK](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) on the server to verify the idtoken. But I'm wondering if this is overkill and unnecessarily complex. Firebase has [a REST interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-get-account-info) that lets me issue a simple POST using cURL or Guzzle and get the users data back, or an error message if the idtoken was expired or invalid.

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=<API_KEY>
```

Request body

`{"idToken":"<Firebase ID-token>"}`

Response body

```
   {
     "kind": "identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse",
     "users": [
       // User data
     ]
   }
```

or an error:

- `INVALID_ID_TOKEN`

  The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.
- `USER_NOT_FOUND`

  There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

This is a lot less complex than using the Admin SDK. From what I can understand the major benefit of using the Admin SDK is that one can verify tokens locally, using private/public keys. But in my case, I only need to verify the token once, at the moment of login, and then use an oldschool PHP session.

So, would making a REST call be enough to "verify" the Firebase idtoken at the moment of login? Or are there potential security issues in doing so?

Comment: I wonder there might be issues with revoked tokens. (Making a guess) This should be more secure than using sdk. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation

Answer (score 0):

A REST request to identitytoolkit API should be sufficient.

The SDK provides a lot of method that you can utilize for managing user data, such as updating name, managing database access/etc. If your app does not need to do any of it - your code should work just fine with REST Calls.

Moreover, the SDK's simple method of verifying tokens does not check for [revoked tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation) as it requires a call to Firebase Backend. In case of REST call though, it would be verified.

And finally as your app makes a call only once (and maintains session thereafter), the overhead shouldn't be much.

Comment: Small addition: you can actually check for token revocation with the SDK 